# Numerical integration of Lorenz Equations with time dependent r

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve question 9.5.4 from Strogatz's Nonlinear dynamics and chaos that asks us to plot hysteresis between a fixed point and a strange attractor. We're supposed to let r=24.4+sin(omega*t) where "omega is small compared to typical orbital frequencies on the attractor. Unfortunately, I don't really know much about numerical integration and I was wondering if someone could give me some hints on this. Here's my attempt:

```
sigma = 10;
b = 8/3;
omega = 1;
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == sigma*(y[t] - x[t]), 
y'[t] == (24.4 + sin (omega*t))*x[t] - y[t] - x[t]*z[t], 
z'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 500}];
Plot[{Evaluate[y[t] /. s0]}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This just ends up giving my a straight line which doesn't seem right. I also get the error:

"NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {-9.96534,-40.4127+1.83447 (24.4 +0.0000362053 sin),-55.9906} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {3} at {t,x[t],y[t],z[t]} = {0.0000362053,{1.83447},{0.837931},{21.5729}}."

This seems like a really noob question but I'm very suck so I would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: 1. `sin (omega*t)` should be `Sin[omega t]`, you should always pay attention to the color of code, `sin` is blue, while `Sin` is black. 2. Definition of `x0`, `y0`, `z0` are missing. 3. `s0` should be `s`.

Comment: Yes the Sin[omega t] fixed it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sigma = 10;
b = 8/3;
omega = 1;
x0 = 1; y0 = 1; z0 = 1;
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == sigma*(y[t] - x[t]), 
    y'[t] == (24.4 + Sin[omega*t])*x[t] - y[t] - x[t]*z[t], 
    z'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
    z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 500}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]